# How to remove unused Google+ icons imported from Google Play Services library

Tags: android, google-play-services

I've migrated the AdMobs banner ads to Google Play Services in my Android Studio project. The resulting APK mushroomed from 0.7 MB to over 1.6 MB. Fortunately ProGuard knocked it down to just over 1 MB. I poked around the APK and noticed that 280 kB of "g+" images have been added to

```
res/
 drawable-hdpi
 drawable-mdpi
 drawable-xhdpi
 drawable-xxhdpi
```

[image]

I have no plans to ever use Google+ in this app. It's a utility app and there's no need to deal with social media. 280kB may sound like peanuts compared to multi-Megabyte apps, but being a relatively simple utility, users want it to be as small as possible. It just feels dirty releasing a new version that blows up from ~700 kB to over 1000 kB with no tangible feature improvements for the user.

Ideally I'd like to exclude those icons for just one project, but I could live with a global solution for now.

Comment: "I could live with a global solution for now" -- replace the icons with tiny ones in your copy of the library projects, so there are no compilation issues, but they take up less room. Or, replace them with aliases to some single drawable.

Comment: Interesting. My build.gradle has "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'". Should I copy that over to my project dir and change the depdency reference?  Finding that library is proving tougher than I thought...

Comment: "Finding that library is proving tougher than I thought" -- it's in your SDK installation, assuming you installed it from the SDK Manager. "Should I copy that over to my project dir and change the depdency reference?" -- tactically, yes. I think there may be some long-term solutions for this problem that will be part of the Gradle for Android plugin. And, by going this route, you add maintenance headache, having to deal with upgrades to the library yourself. There may be ways to rip out the images after compilation, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time manually importing the lib. I copied over google-play-services.jar and added it to gradle.build's "compile files" section. It complained "No resource identifier found for attribute 'adUnitId'". I suppose I need to add the appropriate import since the lib is manually added? 
As an alternative experiment, I added a small res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9 bitmap to my project. It successfully overrode the one from GPS.

Comment: "As an alternative experiment, I added a small res/drawable-xxhdpi/common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9 bitmap to my project. It successfully overrode the one from GPS" -- ah, yes, I had forgotten about that. App resources trump those from a library project. That's a simpler solution. You should be able to create a single XML file containing aliases for all of their names to some other drawable, so you don't need a bunch of little PNG files yourself: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Comment: From that documentation and other pages I've read, bitmap resources must have a separate file for each alias. Indeed in experimentation, putting them in a resource block in a single file (similar to doing string resources) doesn't work. So it's a choice of a bunch of XML files or a bunch of small bitmaps. Somewhat surprisingly, the bitmaps are smaller than the XMLs (both compressed and uncompressed)!  Do you have trick to place multiple bitmap resources into a single XML?

Comment: Sheesh, I'm off my game. You are correct that you need individual XML files per drawable alias, as the name of the alias file is used for the resource identifier. I was thinking that there was an `name` or `android:name` attribute that could be used to provide the resource identifier. My sincere apologies for my multiple screw-ups in this comment thread.

Comment: No worries CommonsWare. You've always been helpful, and your comments have led me to a workable solution. Thanks!

Comment: You should check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717670/filtering-resources-from-the-play-services-monolith-to-make-your-apk-smaller

Comment: @Redwarp - Thanks for the heads up. Will look into that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the two best options are to add tiny bitmaps or aliases to the project named the same as the g+ icons. These supersede the icons in the GPS library. The icons are in each of the drawable-* directories with the following filenames:

```
res/
 drawable-hdpi/
 drawable-mdpi/
 drawable-xhdpi/
 drawable-xxhdpi/
        common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_focus_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_focus_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_normal_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_normal_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_icon_pressed_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_disabled_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_disabled_focus_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_disabled_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_focus_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_focus_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_normal_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_normal_light.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_pressed_dark.9.png
        common_signin_btn_text_pressed_light.9.png
        ic_plusone_medium_off_client.png
        ic_plusone_small_off_client.png
        ic_plusone_standard_off_client.png
        ic_plusone_tall_off_client.png
```

I created a tiny 9-patch bitmap copied and named as each of those files in the drawable dirs. You can barely see it here --->
[image: very tiny]

The alternative is to create aliases. One bitmap alias per file so you end up with the same number of files. For example:

```
res/
 drawable/
        blank.png
 drawable-xxhdpi/
        common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_dark.9.xml
        ...
```

Each of the alias XMLs references the tiny one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/blank" />
```

The size difference is negligible between the tiny bitmap and the alias. Yes it's a hack, but until Google/ProGuard automatically removes unused bitmaps, this may be the only way to recover the wasted space. Thanks to CommonsWare for the assist.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Gradle you can use the [shrinkResources](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) option in combination with ProGuard to exclude resources. This deletes both your resources, as well as resources that your depndencies are using.

```
buildTypes {
  release {
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources true
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
  }
}
```

As of April 2015 there still seems to be a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80872) because of which some resources (including Google Play icons) would not get removed. You can work around this by creating a `keep.xml` file and specifying which resources should be removed. Remember to test your APK after that because removing resources that are actually needed might crash your app!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:discard="@drawable/common_signin_*,@drawable/ic_plusone_*,@drawable/powered_by_google_*"/>
```

Removing these images reduces the size of the APK by about 300kB.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error:

" ...\Application\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\7.3.0\res\drawable-xxhdpi\common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png ERROR: Unable to open PNG file "

Android studio was unable to open the common_signin_btn_icon_disabled_focus_light.9.png file.

To solve this I moved the project folder directory up a level or two to reduce path length. Everything worked perfectly after that.

I used "D:\the_project_folder". Worked for me. No more compile errors.

thanks to this link:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-XYZTouristAttractions/issues/2

Cheers!

Comment: Im not sure this really answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

As a simpler alternative, just delete the .png files in drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-xhdpi and drawable-hdpi, leaving the ones in drawable-mdpi. Of course, check that the filename also exists in drawable-mdpi, first.

Leaving one valid resolution is safer IMHO and the drawable-mdpi files take up less than 30KB which may be acceptable for many people.

Comment: I did try that but the generated APK still has all the bitmaps. It looks like gradle (?) is pulling in the compiled GPS library so I'd need to modify that. Haven't had any luck doing that though.

Comment: Hmm, I'm only using Eclipse ADT plugin, so sorry, I cannot help you there. Would be useful if you could post any follow ups later though.