# Filtering resources from the Play Services monolith to make your APK smaller

Tags: android, gradle, apk

A lot has been written about the monolithic nature of the Google Play Services and why it should be split into more libraries. For now the workaround to keep your APK small is to use proguard to strip out unused references. This works pretty well for classes.dex, but not for the included resources.

I get around 1 MB of additional unused resources and with a bundled Android Wear app this overhead doubles. So my APK is 2 MB larger than needed.

I'm wondering whether there is some straightforward way in Gradle to exclude some resources coming from the dependencies AARs from the resulting APK.

It seems that [the AAPT options in the Gradle Android plugin only allow filtering assets](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-aapt-options).

I was thinking about hooking in some custom aapt script which would call remove for a list of resources using aapt before signing the APK for release.

Does someone else have a simpler solution?

Comment: A non-gradle alternative to Petr's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22967839/how-to-remove-unused-google-icons-imported-from-google-play-services-library

Comment: The gradle solution should be more portable. Haven't tried it yet but I like the approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After some research I found the following sub-optimal solution. I had to list all the not needed resources manually (luckily patterns are applicable) and make sure also to delete all files where they are referenced. Below is an example which makes my Wear app APK from 1.5 MB into 300kb and the APK is working normally without issues.

I had to create my own task `stripResources` and hook it between standard Android plug-in tasks: `mergeReleaseResources` and `processReleaseResources`.

```
task stripResources << {
    println "Custom resource stripping in: $buildDir"
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/layout/confirmation_activity_layout.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/layout/watch_card_content.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/common_signin*.png")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/drawable/common_signin*.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/generic_confirmation*.png")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/drawable/confirmation_*.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/drawable/card_background.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/card_frame*.png")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/go_to*.png")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/drawable/go_to_*.xml")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/ic_plusone*.png")
    delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/powered_by_google*.png")
    // if you only have English you can teh following to filter out some GPS texts wich also take few hundreds of kb
    // delete fileTree(dir: "$buildDir", include: "**/values-*/values.xml")
}

    tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
        if (task.name == 'processReleaseManifest') {
            task.dependsOn stripResources
        }
    }
```

You can do a similar task for regular Android APK.

Comment: Will this snippet delete our own module's resources (when they accidentally have same name pattern) as well?

Answer (score 1):

As of version 0.14 of the Android Gradle plugin, this can be accomplished automatically as mentioned in [this post](https://plus.google.com/+TorNorbye/posts/eHsStybrrBf):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
}
```

`shrinkResources` is a flag that tells the compiler to skip any resources that aren't referenced. `minifyEnabled` is the new name for `runProguard`, which must be enabled for `shrinkResources` to work.

Comment: Actually, I have `minifyEnabled` set to `true` and these assets still are included in the app.

Comment: You need both `minifyEnabled` and `shrinkResources`. You also might have Proguard rules prevent Proguard from deleting the unused classes in the library, which would in turn prevent `shrinkResources` from deleting the images.

Comment: I also have `shrinkResources` set to `true`, and no explicit rules that would prevent Google Play from being optimized.

Comment: [Are you sure it's being optimized properly?](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#whyareyoukeeping)

Comment: I have `-dontoptimize` turned on, so the code isn't being optimized.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Petr Nalevka's insightful answer I have come up with the following solution (a.k.a. ugly hack).

This code removes all PNG drawables under hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi, and so on, keeping only the drawables under mdpi (the ones with the smallest file size). Drawables are only removed if they have a sibling under mdpi, that is if they can be safely removed. Google Play Services should remain fully functional.

A task gets registered for each application variant, so this code works with multiple product flavors.

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def variantCamelName = variant.name.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + variant.name.substring(1)
    def stripResourcesTask = task("strip${variantCamelName}Resources") {
        doFirst {
            def resDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/$variant.dirName"
            def gpsDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms"
            fileTree(dir: "$gpsDir", include: "**/drawable-*/*.png").each { resFile ->
                if (!resFile.parentFile.name.endsWith("-mdpi")) {
                    def resName = resFile.name
                    def resDirName = resFile.parentFile.name
                    def mdpiFile = "$resFile.parentFile.parentFile/drawable-mdpi/$resName"
                    if (file(mdpiFile).file) {
                        def files = fileTree(dir: "$resDir", include: "**/${resDirName}/${resName}")
                        // files.each { f -> println "Deleting $f..." }
                        delete files
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    tasks["merge${variantCamelName}Resources"].finalizedBy stripResourcesTask
}
```

Tested with Android Studio 1.3.0, Gradle plugin version 1.3.0, build tools version 22.0.1 and GPS version 7.5.0.

I'm a bit of a Groovy noob, so this is probably not the most elegant solution.